# Inheriting one overloaded method

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I'm fairly new to C# and OOP, and I have a question in regards to inheritance.

Say I have:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    protected Command()
    {
    }

    public abstract string Execute();

    public abstract string Execute(object o);
}

public class CommandA : Command
{
    public override string Execute()
    {
    }
}

public class CommandB : Command
{
    public override string Execute(object o)
    {
    }
}
```

There are obvious errors due to `CommandA` not implementing `Execute(object o)` and `CommandB` not implementing `Execute()`.

My question, then, is whether there is code I need to implement to avoid these errors? Are empty methods allowed?

Comment: The base class (the class the others inherit from) should have only methods defined that the other classes share.

Comment: Maybe `public abstract string Execute(object o = null);`?

Comment: No. You will have to override abstract class's abstract methods.
To avoid it dont make base class as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You're abusing the use of `abstract` if you're expecting sub-classes to not actually implement some of the methods. `abstract` is used to enforce that the base class *must* implement the functionality. What should happen if someone called `new CommandB().Execute()`?

In some cases, a design may be incorrect and you end up in the situation you're in. In these cases, its somewhat common (though in my opinion a code smell), to do the following:

```
public class CommandA : Command
{
    public override string Execute()
    {
    }

    public override string Execute(object o)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

A somewhat cleaner approach:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    protected Command()
    {
    }

    public abstract string Execute(object o = null);
}
```

Though you're still going to have to deal with the fact that someone may pass an object to `CommandA`.

If the commands have such different behaviour, it's likely they shouldn't both be subclassing the same abstract class.

Comment: Thanks - I've changed the code around to redirect the inheritance for proper coding practice!